# Odd NullPointerException

Tags: java

Stacktrace from my NPE starts with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.yourvision.crm.web.servlets.listExport.ProductListExport.writeCells(ProductListExport.java:141)
```

Line number 141 in this file is:

```
Double availablePieces = store != null ? store.getAvailablePieces() : 0.0;
```

Where store is not null and store.getAvailablePieces() is null. I do not understand why I get exception in here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Believe the JVM.  IDE and debugger will help you sort this out.

Comment: @Zimi There is no issue with store.getAvailablePieces() as store is not null. But I suspect that as getAvailablePieces() is null so it will assign null to availablePieces which is of Double Wrapper reference. In further down the code check whther autoboxing/unboxing is happening. This might causing NPE.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm 99% sure this is because of the behaviour of the conditional operator. I believe your code is equivalent to:

```
double tmp = store != null ? store.getAvailablePieces() : 0.0;
Double availablePieces = tmp;
```

In other words, it's unboxing the result of `store.getAvailablePieces()` to a `double`, then boxing back to `Double`. If `store.getAvailablePieces()` returns `null`, that will indeed cause a `NullPointerException`.

The fix is to make the third operand `Double` as well:

```
Double availablePieces = store != null ? store.getAvailablePieces()
                                       : Double.valueOf(0.0);
```

Now there won't be any boxing or unboxing, so it's fine for `store.getAvailablePieces()` to return `null`. You may want to then use `0.0` instead, but that's a different matter. If you're going to do that, you can change to:

```
Double tmp = store != null ? store.getAvailablePieces() : null:
double availablePieces = tmp == null ? 0.0 : tmp;
```

Comment: Eclipse seems to be giving an error *Cannot cast from double to Double* when you give `(Double) 0.0;` in the ternary operator. Any idea why?

Comment: @R.J: Not entirely sure, but I've changed it to just explicitly use Double.valueOf now :)

Comment: @Obalix: Your edit significantly changed the meaning of a *lot* of the post. The difference between `Double` and `double` is crucial - the only spelling mistake which needed fixing was one in the middle of some text (`Dobule`, I think). I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: @JonSkeet I haven't thought about this that way but certainly you're correct. Thank you

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, tried to fix problems I saw with an earlier edit, that also corrected the spelling.